# Indexing data from S3 into Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, indexing, elasticsearch

I store hundreds of millions of files in S3.  I index these files with Elasticsearch.  Generally, it's incremental, and speed is not a major concern.  Occasionally, I will need to index the entire set.  I'm trying to decide if our internal API should retrieve the file content via the S3 SDK and return it, or if our internal API should just return the S3 URL and let the indexers download the file.

What are the benefits and caveats of indexing directly via the S3 HTTP address versus using the S3 SDK?

I realize S3 is, perhaps, orders of magnitude slower than indexing from a local disk.  This is not my concern.